# Not worth spending your money on

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

Let's say there is a salesperson who are trying to entice their product that you believe it is extremely **not worthy to spend your money**(just a salestalk) Do you say:

> Nah, it's not worth it spending your money on this thing.

Or

> it's not worth the money to spend on this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's not worth it, spending money on this thing" is fine, but you can remove the redundant second "it".

> It's not worth spending X on Y.
>
> It's not worth spending X to do Y.

As you guess, you don't have to use "spend".  You can simply say:

> X isn't worth the Y.

Examples:

> My boss wants me to spend way too much time at the office, but **it's not worth what he's paying me**.
>
> I don't get it.  **It's not worth spending all the time and money on building a giant wooden thing for Burning Man**, if in the end you're just going to burn it.

Comment: The examples here have confused me, they are different from your answer coz you changed the pronouns and the object. Still thx

Comment: Can I say... ''it's not worth spending money enrolling on your course''?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to say "this thing" at all.

> It's not worth spending your money on it.

Also, assuming that the person you are speaking to knew what "thing" you were talking about, you could shorten it down to:

> It's not worth it.

Which means the same thing.

Comment: Thx. But can I say 'it's not worth the money?''

Comment: Yes that works too.

Comment: Wait up hehe, is it worth the spend or worth the money?

Comment: Don't they both mean the same thing? When you say worth the money, the implication is that you want to know if it's worth spending it.

Comment: Mostly yeah, coz I already said 'it's worth the spend' but the other one is different, it may be 'worth the spend(time, energy).

Comment: @JohnArvin  "spend" is not a noun (except with some colloquial meanings), so you would not say "it's not worth the *spend*".  You have to say it's not worth spending *something*.

Comment: The *expense* is the noun.